# Working with Generic classes with different constraints

Tags: c#, generics

I have two legacy C# user controls I need to work together. 
I have an existing dialog onto which I need to add an existing generic usercontrol.

I have tried to sample the hierarchy below

```
interface Foo<T> {}
interface Bar<T> 
{
    T DataObject { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA<T> where T : Foo<T>
{
    public ClassA(T dataObject)
    {
        //Do stuff if T implements Bar<T> - Pseudocode ahead
        if(var T is Bar<T>)
        {
            var x = new ClassB<T>();
            //x is typesafe, and I can set DataObject
            x.DataObject = dataObject;
        }
   }
}

public class ClassB<T> where T : Bar<T> 
{
   T DataObject { get; set; }
}
```

The existing dialog, `ClassA` currently don't have any generic contraints, but could easily be changed to require T implementing `Foo<T>`.
The userControl, `ClassB` is based on another interface, `Bar<T>`. In practice, `Bar<T>` objects always implements `Foo<T>` - in theory of course not.

Are there any construction I can use to declare an object of type `ClassB`, and get compile time validation?

The construction above will give me a compile error stating:

> The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type
>   of method `ClassB<T>`. There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'T' for `Bar<T>`

I can make the `ClassB` object with Reflection, setting the properties using Reflection as well - but I would prefer a compile time solution.

But in my current situation with two existing dialogs - i'm not sure I am able to.

Any help is appreciated - also just if it is stating what I expect, that it can't be done.

--EDIT

Trying to elaborate a bit. 
The problem rises when I have a `ClassC` that implements both `Foo<T>` and `Bar<T>`

```
public class ClassC<T> : Foo<T>, Bar<T>
{
   T DataProperty
}
```

If I make an instance of `ClassA<ClassC>`, that is `T` in the specific instance is `ClassC` - then is there a way in code I can use `T` in creating an instance of `ClassB`- in this case `T` in `ClassA` does live up to the `ClassB` constraints, since `T` is `ClassC`.

I havent figured out how or if possible - tend to believe I can't.

As I wrote above, I have a solution based on reflection, i'm just not fan of using reflection and getting run-time validation only. But in this case with two legacy objects that need to work together I might be running out of options.

Comment: You code will not compile - `ClassB<T>` does not contain a definition for `DataObject`.  It may be possible but not with the construct you have now.

Comment: DataObject is a property on `Bar<T>`, not on `ClassB<T>`,  Your if statement should probably contain `if (dataObject is Bar<T>) { var dataObjectBarT = dataObject as Bar<T>;` which would get you your dataObject as a `Bar<T>`  but it is unclear what you are looking for after that.

Comment: Code edited so B explicitly defines DataObject property.

Comment: *I have a ClassC that implements both Foo<T> and Bar<T>* how can you have multimorphism in C#?

Comment: Foo and Bar is interfaces

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your types are a bit weird. They are kind-of recursive, with `ClassB<T>` requiring a `T` that implements `Bar<T>` which has the same structure as `ClassB<T>`. Maybe you meant to `ClassB<T>` to *implement* `Bar<T>` instead of requiring it as a type parameter?

---

Anyway you cannot do this. In order to be able to write `ClassB<T>`, the compiler needs to ensure that `T` is a valid type parameter for `ClassB<>` *at runtime*. This can only be the case when the type parameters on `ClassA<T>` for `T` are at least as restrictive as the ones from `ClassB<T>`.

Unfortunately, even a hard type check which would ensure that this is the case will not allow you to write `ClassB<T>`.

So without being able to write `ClassB<T>`, you will not be able to get static type safety at compile-time. So even when you create an instance of `ClassB<T>` (which you can), you won’t be able to access `DataProperty` on it since you will not be able to cast it as a `ClassB<T>`.

So in order to solve this, you would either have to access `DataProperty` using reflection only, or call a method inside `ClassA<T>` that does have the type constraint. I’ll show you both solutions:

```
public class ClassA<T>
    where T : Foo<T>
{
    public ClassA(T dataObject)
    {
        if (typeof(Bar<T>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            // method 1, calling a generic function
            MethodInfo mi = typeof(ClassA<T>).GetMethod("SetBDataObject").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Bar<T>));
            mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { dataObject });

            // method 2, doing it all with reflection
            Type type = typeof(ClassB<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
            object x = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            type.GetProperty("DataObject").SetValue(x, dataObject);
        }
    }

    public object SetBDataObject<TB> (TB obj)
        where TB : Bar<TB>
    {
        var x = new ClassB<TB>();
        x.DataObject = obj;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that probably is confusing in your code, is that you have used the same letter `T` as the Type parameter in both classes `ClassA<T>` and `ClassB<T>`.

I'll start by stating the obvious:
when you call `var x = new ClassB<T>();` the constraint for `T` here is in the context of `ClassA<T>` (i.e. `T : Foo<T>`), while `new ClassB<T>()` expects `T` to match the constraint of `T : Bar<T>`.

It seems to me that underlying reason for the issue you are having is a design problem. It looks like you a little mix up between `types` and `classes`.

Lets walk it through:
from the [Gang of Four Design Patterns book](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/gofpatterns.aspx):

> An objects's **class** defines how the object is implemented .The class
>   defines object's internal state and the implementation of its
>   operations.
>
> In contrast, an objects's **type** only refers to its interface -the set
>   of requests to which it can respond.
>
> An object can have many type, and object of different classes can have
>   the same type.

The usage of interfaces in your code implies coding against `types` (that's good!).
Checking for `if (dataObject is Bar<T>)` and upon the result constructing a `ClassB<U>` where `!typeof(U).Equals(typeof(T)` implies heavily relying on implementation (e.g. `class`).

If you ask me, I think you should try one of the following:

1. Use the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for constructing `ClassB`. In the dedicated factory you can add some more logics and verifications in order to decide *how* to construct it (from your code, it is not clear since the types do not match...).
2. If possible, resolve the relation between `Foo<T>` and `Foo<T>` and declare the constraints in the interfaces. In that case, both interfaces should have same constraints fto `T`

Comment: Your observations is somehow correct. Since I am working with two legacy components they vary a bit in their class vs. type focus.
I cannot easily fix ad. 2, as this is legacy both types requires quite a bit to restructure. 
Ad. 1. is actually a bit of what I am doing with reflection - I am just asking to get a ClassB - if T is a wrong type, so constraints don't allow it in ClassB, I return null and handles that situation.

Comment: @ankhansen the advantage of using factory, is that no matter how ugly your code gets (yup, legacy is often ugly...) the ugliness stays contained in a dedicated place... Another option: can the interfaces inherit one another? if so, you can probably use [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)